# updatepanel problem or possible bug

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

I have `TextBox` (multiline) and `Label` in an `UpdatePanel` which I refresh with javascript `__doPostBack(upEditReminder,id);`

Then I set both `Label` and `TextBox` text to current DateTime.

```
protected void upReminder_Onload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lbTest.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    tbReminder.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
```

Problem is that `Label` is updated but `TextBox` date is updated only once when the page is loaded but not when `__doPostBack(upEditReminder,id);` is triggered.
I cant figure out what the problem is.

I have also tried textarea `runat="server"` but still have the same problem.

Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: Already tried making a label of it and see what happens then?
My guess is that you can't update your textbox more then once.

Comment: when i changed it to label then it updates perfectly

Comment: Why not do it with simple javascript? It's a lot simpler and better in every way.

Comment: because i have also few other asp user controls in this control what i can't control with js + i have already working app

Comment: @Woland, You can control everything with js. But if you don't want to change it now (I can understand that). I would suggest that you do it the simple way next time. Doing stuff server side that belongs on the client side pretty much alway gets you into trouble and make your application run slower.

Comment: Look the sample is just a illustrative real app is quite different.  i need to get data from db and i need to to some stuff with this data also i don't like webservices  and  for what updatepanel is for then?

Comment: @Woland, Ok, then I understand. My view on updatepanels is pretty simple: never ever use them. I think it's always a lot easier to write the ajax call yourself with jquery or some other js framework. But thats just a personal opinion.

Comment: Can you please type here the html code also ? The part that is inside the updatePanel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This worked for me... is it different from what you're doing?

aspx code snippet:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" OnLoad="UpdatePanel">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<a href="#" onclick="__doPostBack('UpdatePanel1','');">Update</a>
```

codebehind snippet:

```
protected void UpdatePanel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Label1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
    TextBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```

Clicking the "Update" link triggers the UpdatePanel's postback which refreshes it via ajax and both the label and textarea get the updated timestamp.

Comment: the code is pretty much the same but it is in usercontrol with is placed on the master page

Answer (score 0):

Could you try it after setting EnableViewState as false in that textbox?

Answer (score 0):

Are you setting the textbox text anywhere else in your code behind?  I'm guessing it's getting overwritten somewhere...

Answer (score 0):

Add a button inside the UpdatePanel. Click the button, does it update both label and textbox?

In addition, the call you are making should have the ClientID of the updatepanel which looks something like this:

__doPostBack("ctrl00_ctrl01_upEditReminder",'');

Answer (score 0):

From one of your comments I noticed that you are trying to update a textbox outside of the updatepanel. The problem here is that you cannot update something outside the updatepanel in the updatepanel's postback. That's one of the drawbacks of using an updatepanel.

If you still want to use an updatepanel, I suggest that you update the other page's elements using javascript and preferrable [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) after the updatepanel reload. You could use a hidden input field inside the updatepanel to transfer the data. To refresh the textbox after the update, you could use this JavaScript/jQuery code:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(function () { 
    var reminder = $("[id$='hidReminder']").val();
    $("[id$='tbReminder']").val(reminder);
});
```